# setInterval inside of function not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, setinterval

I'm pretty new to any form of coding so please forgive my ignorance, but when I use a var for my interval for a second function, it will not work correctly, I've tried my best to not have to ask, but my search is fruitless. Please help!

```
    function click_01() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('trash_02');
    setInterval(frame, 10);
    var width = 0
    function frame(){
       if (width >= 100){
            clearInterval("frame");
            width = 0;
       } else {
            width = width + 1;
            elem.style.width = width + '%';
       }
      }

    }


    click_01();
```

Comment: Check my new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a function instead of a string

Just remove quote and parenthesis from function frame. If you pass with quotes it will become string and your code wont work properly.

So here goes your answer

```js
function click_01() {
      
        var intr=setInterval(frame, 100);//here you passed "frame()" which is string
        
        function frame(){
           let elem=document.getElementById('cls');
           elem.style.width=(parseInt(elem.style.width)+1)+'px';
           elem.innerHTML=parseInt(elem.style.width)+"%";
          
          if(parseInt(elem.style.width)>=100){
           elem.style.width=0;
           clearInterval(intr);
            elem.innerHTML='Loading complete';
          }
        }
       }
```

```html
<div id="cls" style="background-color:red;width:0px">

</div>
  <div><button onclick="click_01()"> click to launch loader</botton> </div>
```

Comment: Still it automatically begins without me clicking.

Comment: @Ben The important thing that this answer is trying to illustrate is how one properly users `clearInterval` since it is not being used correctly in the original question.

Comment: Never mind, I was being foolish, thank you for the help!